# Blurring skin in image using OpenCV.js

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

I am building a Javascript library which takes an image as an input, the output image will have all the human skin blurred like below.

I have got this script in python, which is working perfectly (example below) and I am converting it to JS using Opencv.js. The issue is I am not able to replicate the following line of code in Javascript.

```
out[global_mask>0] = blur[global_mask>0]
```

Here,

- out: original image
- global_mask: black and white image where all the skin is white and other parts are black
- blur: blurred copy of the original image.

Can someone please guide me on this, I have tried creating an ROI on the original image and tried placing the black and white image over it. In my mind the path to achieve this is

1. Make all the black pixels in the black and white image transparent
2. Replace the white pixels in the black and white image with the pixels of blurred image at same position.
3. Place the new image over the original image.

[image]  [image]

Comment: your question should be titled "how to use masks for assignment in opencv.js". you probably need `copyTo` or something like that, with an explicit mask argument

Comment: I used copyTo and it worked, thank you.

Comment: related https://forum.opencv.org/t/blurring-skin-in-image/5368

Comment: Yes, that's my question. I asked it on that forum too. 